# Infer a proportion CI from the difference of 2 incidence rate CI

Tags: confidence-interval

In an article, one could read the value of 2 incidence rates per 100,000, with their confidence intervals:

- Treatment (A): $7.3\ [6.1 - 8.5]$
- Control (B): $14.2\ [12.2 - 16.1]$
- Difference (B-A): $7.0\ [4.6 - 9.2]$

The value I'm interested in is the ratio of $\frac{B-A}{B}$, which is estimated at 48.6% here.

Is there any way I could infer the confidence interval of this value with only this information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Assuming you know the variance and covariance for A and B, you can use the delta method to compute variances of functions of these two statistics.

Let $\beta = [a,b]^T$, and let $h(\beta) = (\beta_1 - \beta_2)/\beta_1$

Then $$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}(h(\beta)) =\nabla h(\beta)^{T} \cdot(\Sigma / n) \cdot \nabla h(\beta)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Very interesting! A and B are supposed to be independent and I think I can infer the variance from somewhere in the article. Could you provide a link where I could learn more about this?

Comment: @DanChaltiel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method.  Also, there is almost certainly an example similar to your question in Biostatistical Methods 2ed by Lachin.

Comment: The quality of the approximation will depend on the sample sizes.

Comment: @MickyboYakari This is so for everything in statistics.

Comment: First, I didn't think I'd need to bring attention explicitly to the difference between exact and approximate methods, Secondly, I'm sure you know how bootstrapping compares with asymptotic methods for relatively small sample sizes.

Comment: @MickyboYakari Bootstrapping requires actual data, doesn't it? I stated that I only had confidence intervals, read from an article.

Comment: @DanChaltiel I just realised I mistranslated the question to 'how would you calculate a confidence interval for this particular function of the parameters?'